# facebook login with codeigniter working in localhost but not working on server

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

```
function fblogin(){
    $base_url=$this->config->item('base_url');
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' =>  $this->config->item('appID'), 
        'secret'=> $this->config->item('appSecret'),
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user){
        try{
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            $params = array('next' => $base_url.'Poll/logout');

            $ses_user=array(
                'User' => $user_profile,
                'logout' => $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params)
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($ses_user);
            header('Location: '.$base_url);
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            $user = NULL;
        }       
    }
    echo error_log($e);
    $user = $this->session->userdata('User');
    echo $user['id'];
    $this->load->view('main');
}
```

when echo error_log($e) shows (1)
and var_dump(error_log($e)) shows bool(true)

but in localhost working fine

Comment: Have you updated the Site URL on your Facebook App at http://developers.facebook.com?

Comment: yes
when i click on login with facebook shows popup and i accepted and return my website in function fblogin with white page

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with the endpoint, what is the url returned when you invite the user to login (the one from facebook) ?

Comment: http://www.ra2yk.com
login with facebook
first one var_dump(error_log($e)) = bool(true)
The second one echo error_log($e) = 1

Comment: This is the last thing reached 
when i echo $e shows
CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked in php sdk without js
but still dont know reason